# Find the probability or the upper boundary of symmetric matrix with respect to i (specific column and row)

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics

So first of all after trying to solve this question for the last couple of days I just gave up and I hope any of you guys can help me with.

First of all, let me give you guys an example of a matrix 4x4 that called Symmetric matrix in a respect of i if all the value of the rows and the column from the left to right is the same from top to left.

\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 1&1&0&0\\ 1&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}
as you can see this matrix is symmetric in respect of i=3.

another case of a matrix 3x3 which is symmetric in respect of i=1.
\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 1&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}

now randomise an matrix size nxn so each cell has the value of "0" or "1".

- Matrix of size NxN only.
- Each cell can only have value of "0" or "1".
- Draws are independency and randomise so for each cell. (Basically 0.5 chance for a specific cell to hit "0" nor "1").
- $1\le i\le n$

the question is:
calculate the probability or (if impossible) give upper boundary for all the cases:

a. the matrix is symmetric in respect of i=1 OR symmetric in represent of i=2 OR symmetric in represent of i=1 and i=2.

b. there is an i such as that $1\le i\le n$ matrix is symmetric for that i.

c. for all 1<i<n the matrix is symmetric with a respect of i.

so what I came to first of all is that the all matric possibilitys are $\left(n^2\right)^2$ so basically $n^4$ different matrics.
next I though of the cells that I actually "care" and that's basically the row and the column $n+n$ but because I dont care of the shared cell I can subtract the 2 cells so overall $2n-2$ or $2\left(n-1\right)$.
After that I though that I need to take all the pairs of $2n-2$ but I got myself stucked with that.

Thanks and Hope I have explained the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me, but let's try to help

For any matrix, given all the entries with $j \ge i$, there is exactly one choice for the entries $j < i$ that gives a symmetric matrix.

There are $n\,(n-1)/2$ elements to be chosen, so the probability of this matrix being symmetric is

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(n-1)n/2}$$

So probability $1$ for a  $1 \times 1$ matrix, probability $1/2$ for a $2 \times  2$ matrix, probability $1/8$ for a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Your definition of a matrix being symmetrix with respect to $i$, is the same as saying that you will draw a $(n-i+1)\times (n-i+1)$ matrix.

### Edit

From the comments I am understanding that symmetric with respect to $i$ means that the $A_{i,j}=A_{j,i}$ for a fixed $i$ and $j>i$. In that case there are $n-i$ pairs.

##### a.

Given two independent events events $e_1,e_2$ the probability of $e_1$ or $e_2$ is $p(e_1) + p(e_2) - p(e_1)p(e_2)$ (from the inclusion-exclusion principle).

So the probability of the matrix of dimension $n \times n$, $n\ge 2$, having symmetry for $i=1$ (probability $2^{1-n}$) or $i=2$ (probability $2^{2-n}$) is given by

$$2^{1-n} + 2^{2-n} - 2^{3-2n}$$

##### b.

This could be calculated recursively, being $b(n)$ the probability of having the symmetric with respect to some $i$ in a matrix of dimension $n \times n$. Observing that the probability of finding a symmetry for $2 \le i < n$, is equal to the probability of finding some symmetry for in a submatrix of dimension $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ (probability $b(n-1)$). We can calculate $b(n) = b(n-1) + 2^{1-n} - (1 - b(n-1))2^{1-n}$.

I am not going to expand the above recursion, I will simply give you the upper bound $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2^{-k}=1-2^{2-n}$

(notice that I am excluding the symmetry for $i=n$, that has probability $100\%$).

##### c.

In the case that it is symmetric with respect to all $1 < i < n$, that requires checking $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ pairs, so the probability is

$$(1/2)^{(n-1)(n-2)/2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your time into this, I will try to explain it better. the questions asking for not a symmetric matrix but a smaller case of symmetric matrix. we only need to check the cells on the specific i, for example if i=2 for the 2nd matrix in the examples I gave we can see it's symmetric for i=2(only look at the column and row #2) because if we looking on the column and row we can see that  \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\ 1&1&.0\\ 0&.0&1\end{pmatrix} where I put dot it's the cells we have to check for symmetric.

Comment: I assumed it that the symmetry with respect to `i` was the symmetry of the submatrix starting at row and column `i`. Without fully understanding what is the case I can tell you that the probability will of a symmetry test to return `true` is $(1/2)^c$ where $c$ is the number of individual elements that must be checked.

Comment: I though if that as well but for example lets take i=1 with nxn matrix. that's mean we have to check 2n-2 cells but we have to check for each indeviduals pairs. so it can't be $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-2}$

Comment: The number of checks, $a[i,j] = a[j,i]$ is equivalent to $a[j,i] = a[i,j]$, so that counts as one check.

Comment: I see, so if that's the case for every i it would be $\sum _{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{\left(n-1\right)2}{2}}$ ?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I manage to follow up with everything. :)